# Efficiently Merging Adjacent Blocks

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, merge, theory

This is what I am trying to do:
   I have a routine called merge() that regularly gets called. Its task is to merge data structures called "Block" whose content  is a range of integers represented by "s_idx" and "e_idx", denoting the starting index and the end index, respectively. Adjacent blocks are blocks whose ranges can be combined into a new contiguous range. For example, block 3 with range (25,32) and block 4 with range (33,40) are adjacent  and their ranges can therefore be combined to produce a new contiguous range (25,40).  So at the end, there will be only one block left, having combined all the individual blocks to produce the range (0,N-1), where N is the total number of blocks.

My question is : is there any efficient algorithm to perform such an operation?

The current implementation uses an O(N^2) algorithm, which slows down dramatically as the number of blocks grows.

```
for( int i=0 ; i<_merge_list.max()-1 ; i++ )
    {
        for( int j=i+1 ; j<_merge_list.max() ; j++ )
        {
            if( _merge_list.exist(i) && _merge_list.exist(j) )
            {
                if( _merge_list[i]->get_end_idx() + 1 ==    _merge_list[j]->get_start_idx() )
                {
                    _merge_list[i]->set_end_idx( _merge_list[j]->get_end_idx() );
                    _merge_list[i]->set_link( _merge_list[j]->get_block_idx() );


                                    perform(_merge_list[i]);

                    _merge_list.remove(j);          
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: The routine merge() receives blocks from others processors and at some certain points the routine will be called to merge blocks.
When every two blocks have been merged, an operation will be performed on the new block produced as shown by the line : perform(_merge_list[i]);

Comment: So there can be gaps between blocks at any time.

Comment: No, there is no limit imposed.

Comment: For now I assume the correctness as long as it does not exceed the largest representable number.

Comment: [0,5] and [8,12] cannot be merged as they are not contiguous.
However, [0,5],[6,7],[8,12] can be merged as follows : [0,5]+[6,7] = [0,7] and then [0,7] + [8,12] = [0,12].

However, at the end it is always guaranteed that they  all can be merged into one single  block as all the blocks will already have been available.

Comment: Can you have two overlapping blocks in the collection, i.e. could [1, 5] and [3, 7] be in the system at the same time?

Comment: No. All blocks are "disjoint".

Comment: I don't quite understand what is confusing you.
Maybe, I should say the start and the end indices can take any "non-negative integer" as long as they can be still representable on the given machine.

Blocks are disjoint in that their ranges can never overlap, i.e. , [0,4] and [3,5] can never occur.

Comment: Ohh..I think I know what you mean.
When all processors have no more data to contribute, they send a terminating message to the processor which performs the merging operation. This is when I can be sure that I have received all the blocks, which will eventually be combined to produce the "fully merged super block".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all your blocks guranteed to be contiguous? If that's the case it should be trivial to find min,max indices in O(N) time then create one final block, otherwise you could sort the blocks first then merge O(NlogN)  + O(N) = O(NlogN)

If you maintain the blocks in a sorted manner, it only takes O(N) time to merge a block. If you have them all at once then you sort the array of blocks first, then merge. If you get them piecemeal you merge into the array of blocks in a way that maintains the sorted ordering.

Comment: I don't quite understand your idea.
To clarify things, this routine doesn't get called once, but regularly over the runtime.
Additionally, N cannot be determined until the last block comes.
Therefore, a dynamic array (_merge_list is an instance of the dynamic array) is used in my code for this reason.

Comment: many  thanks for the clarification. 

However, blocks are stored in a dynamic array according to their IDs.
Therefore, they are always kept sorted.

Comment: @takwing If the blocks are always kept sorted then you can always merge in O(N) time, just iterate over the sorted block list and merge.

Comment: ohh..you are right.
I wish there were some quicker algorithm of the O(log N) class...

However, this thread is still open to new ideas...haha

Comment: When you receive a block if you know what the received block is you can merge directly O(1) after finding the location where you need to add it O(logn) via a binary search.

Comment: A quicker way is possible, but will cost you more overhead. Since a block can only be merged to its left or right neighbor, you only need to find out if there is a block with (low-1) and (high+1) high/low adges; these could be kept in two (or one...) hashtables, at the cost of approx 2*2 pointers (which could be kept in the blocks themselves if it were a free list) Yielding O(1) performance. A rangetree would give you O*log(N) performance.